# Half of ImageView overlay Toolbar, the other half overlay the layout

Tags: android

I want half of my ImageView to overlay the toolbar, the other half overlay the layout, exactly like in the image below, and it should work for all resolutions. How can i achieve it?

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k40h.png)

My layout for now looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.PasswordAddActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/add_activity_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>


    <com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/name_of_website_textinputlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_name_of_website"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/name_of_website"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout>


    <com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/website_address_textinputlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_website_address"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/website_address"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout>


    <com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/username_textinputlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_username"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout>


    <com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_textinputlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_password"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_generate_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/generate_password"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I dont want a solution like adding martionTop or something like this, it should be more general, which will work in mostly/all devices.

Comment: This is often done with a FloatingActionButton, you can search for various examples of that for more code samples.

Comment: Use `CoordinatorLayout` as a parent layout for this task.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code you can use. Hope this helps. There is more than one way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your toolbar inside a FrameLayout and inside that same FrameLayout add the image. Position the image with gravity (center horizontal) and some margin top (in dp).

When you want to position an element over another one use FrameLayout (or CoordinatorLayout if it wraps all the content of the Fragment).

Your layout upadted with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.PasswordAddActivity">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/add_activity_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>


    <com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/name_of_website_textinputlayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
      app:errorEnabled="true">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name_of_website"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/name_of_website"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout>


    <com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/website_address_textinputlayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      app:errorEnabled="true">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_website_address"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/website_address"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout>


    <com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/username_textinputlayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      app:errorEnabled="true">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_username"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout>


    <com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/password_textinputlayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      app:errorEnabled="true"
      app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    </com.example.fiekpasswordmanager.CustomTextInputLayout>


    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/et_generate_password"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:text="@string/generate_password"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Another way could be transforming all to constraint layout, there is more than one solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `RelativeLayout` as the root layout, and placing the `ImageView` below the `Toolbar`, then give the `margin_top` to "negative half your image height".